# Is there anyway to clear Firebase notoficaion programitally?

Tags: python, django, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Firebase, I want to control the notification from django which is going to the android devices of the customer. I want to make sure that if the email if seen from any device either from desktop or any other means, the Firebase notification should be deleted, as the email is already seen.

**Any help will be appriciated.**